# This code does not work: im trying to get two columns of a csv file at two lists

Tags: python-3.x, loops, csv, append

Im trying to get two columns of a csv file in two different lists. the method works for one list but when i tried to make another for loop in the same way, it behaved differently. what is wrong with my code.

```
import csv
with open('matplotlibexperiments\Weather Data in India from 1901 to 2017.csv') as file:
    csvreader=csv.reader(file)
   
    header_row=next(csvreader)
    years=[]
    julytemp=[]   

    for column in csvreader:
       
        years.append(column[1])
        pass
       
    for c in csvreader:
        julytemp.append(c[7])
    print(julytemp)
```

the csv file is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnwph.png)

i tried to make the loop nested hoping that it would work, but it din't. it just prints one list if not nested and prints the other one if nested.

Answer (score 0):

Your `csv.reader(file)` as an iterator exhausts after one full iteration, so for the second it's already "empty".

You can fill both lists in one cycle though

```
import csv
with open('matplotlibexperiments\Weather Data in India from 1901 to 2017.csv') as file:
    csvreader=csv.reader(file)
   
    header_row=next(csvreader)
    years=[]
    julytemp=[]   

    for column in csvreader:
        years.append(column[1])
        julytemp.append(column[7])
```

Comment: Thanks. I did precisely this with the logic "Maybe two for loops don't work...". now I get the proper reason